# Connect to remote mysql server from ubuntu fails

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I'm using AWS server (ubuntu) for backup my remote mysql db, using mysqldump command.
Since I changed the db password, I cannot connect anymore remotely from the machine using `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` configuration file.

When I'm using the command

```
mysql -u root -h 1.1.1.1 -p 123456
```

It's connects successfully, but when I'm trying to connect by using the mysql configuration file `/my.cnf` by typing just

```
mysql
```

I gets the error message :

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I restarted the db server (I don't need mysql service running on aws because I connected remotely)

I don't want to connect through any socket

`my.cnf` file content:

```
[client]
port = 3306
host = 1.1.1.1
user = root
password = 123456

[mysqld]
user = mysql
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address    = 1.1.1.1
```

I don't know what have changed, except from the password, I didn't change anything neither in the db itself and in the config file, so I have no idea why it stopped working.

Comment: Also `passowrd` is misspelled.

Comment: @AvihooMamka I just put the password for the example

Answer (score 2):

Add in the my.cnf the line **protocol=tcp**

```
[client]
port = 3306
host = 1.1.1.1
user = root
password = 12345
protocol = tcp
```

That force MySQL to use TCP and not the socket connection

Comment: @Karin Lahyani - is there a other cnf file like .my.cnf in the home directory. try : # **find / -name ".my.cnf"** to find it

Comment: @Karin Lahyani - the client look to the file in that order **/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf**  You can also try **mysql  --protocol=tcp**

Comment: runs the client and the database on the same server ??

Comment: when im using **mysql --protocol=tcp** I gets the error : 'ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111)'
Why does it think that I'm trying to connect from local host? my bind-address is my destination ip

Comment: can you reach the destination server via ping - # ping destination-ip . if you can reach install nmap a scan the destination. i am nearly sure that the destination server has no open ports

Comment: The code is running on AWS, I'm trying to backup my - so the db is on different server and I connect it remotely.

Comment: ping is working, so the command mysql -r root -h 1.1.1.1 -p, so it cannot be block